# Can this error during appcenter upload in fastlane safely be ignored?

Tags: fastlane, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I am using fastlane in an iOS project, and am trying to do uploads of the app to app center for distribution to QA testers.  I'm seeing an error from the fastlane appcenter plugin about an invalid distribution group, but then the plugin successfully uploads and distributes to the distribution group.  I am just wondering if anybody has an idea of what is causing the error message and whether it is something to worry about and if so how to correct it, or if it is something I can safely ignore.  Here's a dump of the relevant part of the output from fastlane:

```
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:50.26]: ------------------------------
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:50.26]: --- Step: appcenter_upload ---
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:50.26]: ------------------------------
ERROR [2021-11-09 10:17:50.78]: Not found, invalid distribution group name BlahBlahBlah
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:50.78]: Starting release upload...
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:51.05]: Setting Metadata...
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:51.25]: Metadata set
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:51.25]: Uploading release binary...
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:52.63]: Chunk uploaded
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:53.25]: Chunk uploaded
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:53.96]: Chunk uploaded
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:54.32]: Chunk uploaded
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:54.32]: Binary uploaded
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:54.32]: Finishing release...
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:54.50]: Upload finished
INFO [2021-11-09 10:17:54.63]: Waiting for release to be ready...
INFO [2021-11-09 10:18:02.50]: Release '2147' committed: https://appcenter.ms/orgs/Blah-Organization/apps/Blah-QA/distribute/releases/2147
INFO [2021-11-09 10:18:02.80]: Release '2147' (8.0.0) was successfully updated
INFO [2021-11-09 10:18:03.36]: Release '2147' (8.0.0) was successfully distributed'
INFO [2021-11-09 10:18:03.36]: Release '2147' (8.0.0) was successfully distributed to group "BlahBlahBlah"
INFO [2021-11-09 10:18:03.36]: Release '2147' is available for download at: https://install.appcenter.ms/orgs/Blah-Organization/apps/Blah-QA
INFO [2021-11-09 10:18:03.36]: Starting dSYM upload...
INFO [2021-11-09 10:18:03.74]: Uploading dSYM...
INFO [2021-11-09 10:18:05.09]: dSYM uploaded
```